# Pygame Scaling Healthbar

Tags: python, math, pygame, 2d-games

I'm working on an RPG like game, where your maximum health can be increased throughout.

I am trying to make a script that will draw a health bar, 100 Pixels Wide, for values over 100.

As your health goes up, the units of the health bar get smaller.

This was the best I could think of:

```
#Draw Bar
import pygame

def SingleColorBar(surface,color,x,y,value,maxvalue):
    xx=0
    for hp in range(value):
        pygame.draw.rect(surface, color, (x+xx,y,1,32), 0)
        xx+= value/100
```

This did not work at all as intended!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could convert your current HP into a ratio of your Max HP then draw your rect that many pixels wide.

```
int(max(min(currentHP / float(maxHP) * health_bar_width, health_bar_width), 0))
```

This should give you the percentage as an integer and fall between 0 and the pixel width of your health bar so you don't overdraw.